# How can I improve this union?

Tags: sql, t-sql, union

The following SQL does almost exactly what I want.

```
SELECT p.ProductNumber "Plan Number",
       p.Name,
       p.price         "Monthly Rate",
       count(*)        "Group",
       '0'             "Direct Debit"
FROM   contact c,
       product p
WHERE  c.integ_schemeid = p.ProductId
       AND c.ParentCustomerId IS NOT NULL
GROUP  BY p.ProductNumber,
          p.Name,
          p.price
UNION
SELECT p.ProductNumber "Plan Number",
       p.Name,
       p.price         "Monthly Rate",
       '0'             "Group",
       count(*)        "Direct Debit"
FROM   contact c,
       product p
WHERE  c.integ_schemeid = p.ProductId
       AND c.ParentCustomerId IS NULL
GROUP  BY p.ProductNumber,
          p.Name,
          p.price
```

With results:

[image]

I want one line for each plan, with group and direct debit values together in one row.

Is this possible in T-SQL?

Comment: JOIN IT TO ITSELF THEN USE COLUMNS THAT HAVE VALUES... ON t1.PlanNumber = t2.PlanNumber and t1.name=t2.name and t1.monthlyrate=t2.monthlyrate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
select p.ProductNumber "Plan Number",p.Name,p.price "Monthly Rate",
    count(CASE WHEN c.ParentCustomerId IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) "Group", 
    count(CASE WHEN c.ParentCustomerId IS NULL THEN 1 END) "Direct Debit"
from contact c,product p 
where c.integ_schemeid = p.ProductId
group by p.ProductNumber,p.Name,p.price
```

On failure of the `CASE WHEN`, the `CASE` will return `NULL`, and `COUNT` doesn't "count" `NULL` values. The `1` is a random value. It only means "not `NULL`". You could have used `'X'`, `'Foo'`, `0`, `-1`...

Comment: I would use SUM approach to avoid NULL warning

Comment: SUM(CASE WHEN c.ParentCustomerId IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) "Group",

Answer (score 0):

OK This query assumes that each name has 2 rows so Ill use inner join

```
select t1.[Plan Number],t1.Name, t1.[Monthly Rate],t1.Group,t2.[Direct Debit] from
(
select p.ProductNumber "Plan Number",p.Name,p.price "Monthly Rate",count(*) "Group", '0' "Direct Debit"
from contact c,product p 
where c.integ_schemeid = p.ProductId
and c.ParentCustomerId is not null
group by p.ProductNumber,p.Name,p.price
)t1
inner join
(
select p.ProductNumber "Plan Number",p.Name,p.price "Monthly Rate", '0' "Group", count(*) "Direct Debit"
from contact c,product p 
where c.integ_schemeid = p.ProductId
and c.ParentCustomerId is null
group by p.ProductNumber,p.Name,p.price) t2
on t1.[Plan Number] = t2.[Plan Number] and t1.name=t2.name and t1.[Monthly Rate] = t2.[Monthly Rate]
```

On this query i use your same computation then join to the other table, you can modify the column you wanted to filter but for column group i used the upper queryand for the column direct-debit i used the lower query